# Is it possible to customize cluster image in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, ios11

I'm using iOS 11 new APIs and I have been successful in making cluster appear. Now, I'm trying to change cluster image providing a custom image. Since I created this custom annotation view:

```
    class PlaceView: MKAnnotationView {
        override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
            willSet {
                guard let place = newValue as? Place else {return}
                clusteringIdentifier = Place.type
                image = place.image
            }
    }
```

I tried to add this line inside willSet block:

`cluster?.image = UIImage(named: "Cluster")`

but it didn't work.

What am I missing? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check to see if the annotation is of type `MKClusterAnnotation`. If it is you can then use the `memberAnnotations` property to access the member annotations. In your case, for example, you could say:

```
override var annotation: MKAnnotation?
{
    willSet
    {
        if let cluster = newValue as? MKClusterAnnotation { 
            image = UIImage(named: "Cluster")
        } else {
            // set image for non cluster
        }
    }
}
```

For more information see WWDC 2017 [What's New with MapKit.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/237/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I completely missed that link! However, I've been able to solve my problem exploring WWDC's sample project: I had to add this line in my View Controller: `mapView.register(ClusterView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)` (I created a new class to customize cluster's MKAnnotationView too)

Comment: Take care with the new register method on MKMapView as it is buggy, you should still use the MKMapViewDelegate methods: forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89427