# Size of custom MKPointAnnotation

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I've a problem with the size of a custom MKAnnotationView.
I set a custom image but when the zoom of the MKMapView change the size of the annotation don't.
I lost the default behaviour of the annotation like disappear in term of the zoom, resizing etc..
Thanks for help.

My Custom Annotation :

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
var pinCustomImageName:String!
var index : Int! }


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let reuseIdentifier = "pin"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    annotationView?.canShowCallout = true;
    let customPointAnnotation = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation

    var image = UIImage(named: customPointAnnotation.pinCustomImageName)
    annotationView?.image = image
    annotationView!.isEnabled = true
    annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
    return annotationView
    }
```

Edit : 
I just wanna my annotation view resize when I zoom in or out the map. And when I am far the annoatation disapear.

Comment: Probable duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286711/resize-mkannotationview-image-when-map-zooms-in-and-out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to customize cluster image in iOS 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100598/is-it-possible-to-customize-cluster-image-in-ios-11)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking? Annotations do not change size when you zoom in/out. Overlays do (they are drawings on the earth surface), but annotations don't (they are just map markers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make annotation disapear use displayPriority

```
 annotationView?.displayPriority = .defaultHigh
```

> static let **required**: MKFeatureDisplayPriority A constant indicating that the item is required.
>
> static let **defaultHigh**: MKFeatureDisplayPriority
>   A constant indicating that the item's display priority is high.
>
> static let **defaultLow**: MKFeatureDisplayPriority
>   A constant indicating that the item's display priority is low.
>   [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkfeaturedisplaypriority)